# Laravel: Ignoring modal template if direct URL access is detected

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am loading my signup/login form in a modal. If the modal fails to load due to javascript restrictions or for whatever reason the signup/login link will act as a normal link and direct the user to the signup/login page.

**Problem:** How can I detect that the page is not being loaded with ajax so that I can apply something along the lines of...

```
 @if(!$modal)
   @extends('fullLayout')
 @else
   @extends('ajaxLayout')
 @endif
```

Answer (score 3):

in the layout:

```
@if(Request::ajax())
  //write the template for ajax request
@else
  //write the template for full layout
@endif
```

the view files will remain same. i.e. they will extend to the same layout.

Comment: I added 

     @if(!Request::ajax())
 @extends("layouts.frontend.page.main")
 @endif

But this just causes "@extends("layouts.frontend.page.main")" to print to the page. Blade isn't interpreting the text.

Comment: dude, above should be in the __layout__, not in the __view__.